# Database Design ,Best Way to save configurations for an organisation

Tags: database, jpa, entity-relationship

In my application i have entities such as Organisations and Users .Every user belongs to an organisation. I want to implement two factor authentication for users based on Organisation settings  Ip (i will save ip range in it) and Geolocation (I will save ,cityName, latitude ,longitude ,and radius).What is the best way to save these settings for an organisation. 
My idea is to create one entity TwoFactorSettings  and to store in it IpConfigs and Geolcation  as different entities.

Is there any better solution ,or more generic structure which can help in this case?

```
@Entity
public class TwoFactorSettings{

  private int id;

  private String createdDate;

  private String createdBy;

  @OneToOne
  private IpConfigs ipConfigs;

  @OneToOne
  private Geolcation geoLocation;


  @OneToOne
  Organisation organisation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since every user belongs to an organization, you could create a one-to-one relationship for user with organization entity. Then create a relationship between an organization and its settings (ipConfigs, and geolocation) entities

```
 @Entity
 public class User {

  @OneToOne(targetEntity=Organization.class)
  @JoinColumn(name="organization_id")
  private Organization organization;

}



@Entity
public class Organization {

  @OneToOne(targetEntity=IpConfigs.class)
  @JoinColumn(name="ipconfig_id")
  private IpConfigs ipConfigs;

  @OneToOne(targetEntity=Geolcation.class)
  @JoinColumn(name="geolocation_id")
  private Geolcation geoLocation;

}
```

Comment: The relation between organisation and user is  @OneToMany , what i want is to find  best way to save  two factor configs for organisations . Currently i want to save configs based on Ip and Geolocation , what if in the future i want to add more 'factors' .? Is it a good way to map directly with organisation Entity

Comment: @M1r1 If you're going to add more factors in the future, then it's better to use a 'TwoFactorSettings', or 'OrganizationDetails' entity. That way the data is more normalized.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization